# How CMAKE_ECLIPSE_EXECUTABLE is used?

Tags: eclipse, cmake

I'm generating Eclipse projects with

```
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles" path_to_src
```

In cmake-gui I can see that `CMAKE_ECLIPSE_EXECUTABLE` is set to `CMAKE_ECLIPSE_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND`

I wonder how `CMAKE_ECLIPSE_EXECUTABLE` is used by cmake? Is this fine not to set this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is okay not to set it. As far as I now, it is used in newer versions (e.g. see the changes by Alex Neundorf [1]) to retrieve the version of the Eclipse executable. Depending on the version, the project generation is changed.

[1] http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/208